How to make React Native compatible with IOS
I'm learning React Native on my own and I ran into an issue. My project works perfectly on the web, but when I try to run it on iOS, I get the following error:
(NOBRIDGE) ERROR Warning: Error: Image: asset with ID "6" could not be found. Please check the image source or packager.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native'
import { getAuth, signOut } from 'firebase/auth'
import { UserDefault } from '../assets/Images'
import { db, auth } from '../firebaseConfig'
import { doc, getDoc } from 'firebase/firestore'

export default function HomeScreen() {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState('')
  const [error, setError] = useState('')

  const onLogOut = () => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    signOut(auth)
  }

  const checkUserData = async (userUid) => {
    try {
      const userDocRef = doc(db, 'user_data', userUid)
      const docSnapshot = await getDoc(userDocRef)

      if (docSnapshot.exists()) {
        const userData = docSnapshot.data()
        setUserName(userData.Name)
      } else{
        {onLogOut}
      }

    } catch (e) {
      setError(e)
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const user = auth.currentUser

    if (user) {
      checkUserData(user.uid)
    } else {
      onLogOut
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image source={UserDefault} style={styles.userImage} />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={onLogOut}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Log Out</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  userImage: {
    width: 128,
    height: 128,
    marginBottom: 16,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  button: {
    marginBottom: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    paddingVertical: 12,
    paddingHorizontal: 30,
    borderRadius: 99,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
})

What I've Tried:

Confirmed that the image path in UserDefault is correct.

Verified the Image source is properly linked to the asset.

Checked React Native documentation for asset usage.

Realized that my project doesn't have ios or android folders. I suspect this might be the issue, but I don't know how to generate them.


My Question:
How can I fix this error? Could it be related to the missing ios and android folders? If so, how do I set them up properly? Any advice on handling assets in React Native for iOS would be greatly appreciated!
